# Excel count columns where values match and value is above threshold

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to find matches between column B and C when the value in A is above a certain threshold.

```
0.99    p269    p269
0.99    p312    p312
0.64    p249    p249
0.64    p247    p247
0.09    p243    p284
```

I'm trying the Countifs method but it doesnt work.

```
=COUNTIFS(
        A1:A31968,">" & F2,
        B1:B31968,C1:C31968
)
```

The first part works (F2 is my treshold), but the I want to check all rows.
So when my threshold is 0.5 I want 4 as a result. When the threshold is 0.08 I still want 4 because the labels of the fifth row don't match. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add a fourth column to spreadsheet in column `D` containing the following formula:

```
=IF(B1=C1, 1, 0)
```

Here is what your spreadsheet looks like now:

```
A       B       C       D
0.99    p269    p269    1
0.99    p312    p312    1
0.64    p249    p249    1
0.64    p247    p247    1
0.09    p243    p284    0
```

In other words, if columns `B` and `C` agree, there is a 1 otherwise 0.  Then, you can use the following `COUNTIFS` formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,">0.5",D1:D5,"=1")
```

Here we check the `0.5` threshhold on column `A` as you were already doing, but we also check that the `B` and `C` values are in agreement.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, you're right, sorry for this typo. Incidentally, my typo would not have changed the count, because the fifth row failed the `A` criteria anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use a pseudo-array formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5>F2)*(B1:B5=C1:C5))
```

to combine the two conditions. It doesn't have to be entered as an array formula, but may have performance issues if used on several thousand rows of data.

[image]